# Customize camera in Layar SDK

Tags: android, layout, camera, overlay, layar

I am integrating Layar SDK in android. I have used below code :-

```
String oauthKey = "xxxxx"; 

String oauthSecret = "xxxxx"; 

LayarSDK.initialize(this, oauthKey, oauthSecret);

LayarSDK.startLayarActivity(this);
```

It works well. Now i want to customise the camera but can not get idea. Its documentation says its possible to do so but don't provide any help.

I want to add Info button on top of camera.

Thanks for Help.